# How to create an array with current time and next 10 five minute interval times using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, time, intervals

I need to create one array in javascript like this. It should contain current time + next 10 times with the interval of 5 mins

> array = [1.45, 1.50, 1.55, 2.00, 2.05, 2.10, 2.15, 2.20, 2.25, 2.30];

How I will create this kind of an array using javascript.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you having problems with? Getting the current time? Adding time to the current time? Do you want the times rounded to the closest multiple of 5? What if the current time is `1:37`, is the first element of the array `1:40`, `1:42` or `1:45`?

Comment: it will be 1:45. I need to create a floating graph with these times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(), interval=5, arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + interval);
  arr.push(date.getHours() + '.' + date.getMinutes());
}
/*
arr is the array you want.
e.g. ["21.17", "21.22", "21.27", "21.32", "21.37", "21.42", 
        "21.47", "21.52", "21.57", "22.2"]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Javascript's Date object. It's a little bit weird to use decimals to represent time. After all, does 1.50 stand for one hour and a half, or for one hour and fifty minutes?

Having said that, here is the code:

```
array = [];
var d = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  array.push( d );
  d = new Date( d.getTime() + 5*60*1000 );  // 5 minutes in milliseconds
}
```

Therefore, the `array` now contains 10 `Date` objects.